# Expression on date field

Tags: sql, date, indexing, expression

I'm trying to refactor some queries to use an index.

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT dateField,valueField
  FROM myTable
 WHERE current_date - dateField <= 30
```

To be able to use an index efficiently, I'd like to get rid of the expression on dateField.

What I was able to refactor it to

```
SELECT dateField,valueField
  FROM myTable
 WHERE dateField >= current_date - 30
```

But I'm not sure if this is correct, given that "30" is a parameter and changes occasionally.

Comment: This should work with a parameter as well as a constant.

Comment: But are those two queries really equivalent?

Comment: if `dateField` has the `DATE` date type, yes, those two queries are equivalent. Otherwise, rounding can make them a bit different.